# OpenCover generates an empty report

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, code-coverage, opencover

I am using [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) to determine code coverage for a simple C# project.

### The problem

Although I can see MSTest running the unit tests (and succeeding) the generated report is empty.

### Details

This is the command I am using:

```
opencover.console.exe -register -arch:32 
                      -target:"%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
                      -targetargs:"/testcontainer:calculatortest.dll"
                      -filter:+[calculator.dll]* -output:coverage.xml
```

### The output

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading calculatortest.dll...
Starting execution...

Results               Top Level Tests
-------               ---------------
Passed                CalculatorTest.StatisticsTest.AddOccurrenceTest
Passed                CalculatorTest.StatisticsTest.AvgTest
2/2 test(s) Passed

Summary
-------
Test Run Completed.
  Passed  2
  ---------
  Total   2
Results file:  e:\Users\erno\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CodeStatistics\CalculatorTest\bin\Debug\TestResults\erno_ERNO01 2011-07-01 14_27_06.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings
Visited Classes 0 of 0 (NaN)
Visited Methods 0 of 0 (NaN)
Visited Points 0 of 0 (NaN)
```

The content of the generated report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoverageSession xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <VisitPoints />
</CoverageSession>
```

### Environment

The code is running on Windows 7 64-bits but is executed in a 32-bit Visual Studio command prompt environment.

**EDIT** I am running the command in the directory with the debug build of the unit tests and I added the OpenCover directory to the environment path.

### What I tried

I searched for similar problems with PartCover (because OpenCover appears to be a sort of branch) but could not find anything that matched the problem and presented a solution.

**EDIT** I also tested with a broader filter `-filter:+[*]*` but this did not change the output in any way.

**EDIT** I also tested with the MSTest `/noisolation` argument [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033012/why-partcover-report-shows-0-when-mstest-runs-successfully-and-all-tests-pass). Still no results.

**EDIT** I also tested by removing the filter completely and falling back to the default filter. No results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the -register:user switch to do per user registration i.e. it registers (and unregisters) without needing full admin rights.

Comment: Wilde, Ah, I spelled that switch wrong: `-register:erno` (never got a message about that either. I will test that too. Thanks!

Comment: It is actually :user all feedback will be well received it is a young project.

Comment: Wilde, Yes, I noticed that after reading your answer. Most of the errors that I am making with OpenCover stem from the lack of documentation, examples and error messages. I know it is a young project that is no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break my mind cleared and I suspected the COM registration that is done by OpenCover so I checked the eventlog.

Indeed the COM registration was failing. So I decided to try and run the command prompt as administrator suspecting I was being hindered by UAC

Running the command including the `/noisolation` flag hangs the process.

Without this flag the report is generated and correctly filled.

I think I will register the COM dll permanently so I can run OpenCover using any credentials that I prefer.

Another thing I might do is add an issue on the OpenCover site stating that it is swallowing an exception. (Unless [Shaun Wilde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189163/shaun-wilde) reads this and beats me to it)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using NUnit 2.6 on Windows XP.
Every report was blank until I added the magical register:user flag.
@Shaun-Wilde, what does this flag exactly do?

Comment: It forces OpenCover to use regsvr32 with the [/n /i:user](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873) which means that the profiler gets registered under HKCU rather than HKLM (when you use -register alone). Some people have the profiler pre-registered (i.e. for use with a service) and then you don't need the switches at all. I thought the Usage guide explained this but if not please suggest improvements i.e. supply alternate wording if you can.

Comment: I already rewrote a part of the usage wiki, but we should be more emphatic on the forced use of register flag, I kept getting blank reports for over an hour and tried lots of things before figuring out the issue. BTW, great tool! Many many thanks!